# Using relative unix home path (Tilde "~") in TSConfig baseUrl?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

In tsconfig.json I am using `baseUrl` to specify the location of my type definitions for Javascript projects, however it requires an absolute unix path.

Is there a way to use relative unix path (not including my unixname?)

Basically I don't want to include my unixname in tsconfig.

Works:

```
...
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "/Users/<MY_USERNAME>/Library/...."
    },
    "files":["script.js"],
    "include": [
      "./**/*",
      "./*.js",
      "*.js",
      "./**/*.js"
  ]
  }
```

Does not work:

```
...
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "~/Library/...."
    },
    "files":["script.js"],
    "include": [
      "./**/*",
      "./*.js",
      "*.js",
      "./**/*.js"
  ]
  }
```

Comment: Can't you use relative baseUrl to location when `tsconfig` file is? like `baseUrl: "./src"`.

Comment: @pie6k I can, but the files are stored in the user's library folder (for a domain-specific reason)

Comment: Then you probably need domain specific solution which I'm not aware of